# Save stdout to hex file

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal

I have my own command line program which I am running on the terminal. How might I redirect the output from this program to file so that I can see a hex representation of it? I also wish the control characters outputted from the program to be saved to hex.

**UPDATE**

My program also receives commands on the terminal via std input. It seems doing:

myprogram 9889 > output.txt

or even

myprogram 9889 | xxd

disrupts the program in some manner such that I cant seem to get the program to respond to inputted commands.

Comment: Why do you need to save it? Just append `| xxd`.

Answer (score 2):

you did not mention the operating system you are using. in Linux you can use `hexdump`

```
your_console_app | hexdump -C
```

Comment: The question is tagged with `linux`

Answer (score 1):

```
program > file.txt
```

This will redirect all `STDOUT` of `program` to `file.txt`

If you want to read more about `redirection`, read [me](http://www.techtrunch.com/scripting/redirections-and-file-descriptors)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.

It's better to save the file *as is*, i.e. save the exact bytes output by your program.

Then, when you want to *display* the data, view it as hexadecimal data.

```
$ program >output.txt
$ hexdump -C output.txt
```

This uses the [hexdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm) program which is common in Linux. You should have it.

Comment: When I try this, only the startup banner from my program is stored to the file. When I start entering data on the stdin (after startup), the responses are missing from the hex log.